# How do servers avoid a quadratic increase in traffic in MMO games?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, server, game-development

Let's say you have a server-authoritative multiplayer online game(the server has the final say of what happens in a game and the clients just render graphics and take user input and give it to the server).

If you have `X` players in one area all next to each other, in visibility of each other, the server must send information to every player about the state of all players.

Positions, current animation, gameplay stats, etc.

This means it has to send `X^2` worth of data. However I have seen games where more than a thousand players clump on one spot and yet it keeps functioning.

This wouldn't be possible if the server was trying to send such absurd amounts of data.

So how is it being done?

Comment: Possibly more suitable for the [gamedev.se] site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the state of other players doesn't require a lot of data. For example, each client could recompute the positions, animation state, stats, etc. of all other players given only their gamepad input. Say there are 16 buttons (bits) which are sampled 10 times per second. This results in 20 bytes of data per player and second, requiring a total bandwidth of 20 * 1000 * 1000 bytes/s = 20 MB/s of total bandwidth for 1,000 players. This data can usually be compressed further by only transmitting (action, timestamp) pairs.

That said, there's simply no way to avoid quadratic space or time complexity in many aspects of MMO games. That's why even today's MMOs typically support only 32-64 players per map, with very few supporting 256 or more.